# actionscript 3 animation shaking problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation

please help me my client is killing me!

here is a link: http://aradon.co.il/test/circles.html

now you see how the circle are shaking!!! my client wont approve it like this.

what can cause that?

it builded like this

one class call Path that have an EnterFrame Event

and 6 Circles that every circle have that:

```
    private var _aPosition:Number = 0;

    public function get aPosition():Number
    {
        return _aPosition;
    }

    public function get aRadians():Number
    {
        return  180 / Math.PI * _aPosition;
    }

    public function set aPosition(value:Number):void
    {
        _aPosition = value % 360;

        if(parentPath)
        {
            x = Math.cos(aRadians) * (parentPath.width / 2);
            y = Math.sin(aRadians) * (parentPath.height / 2);
        }
    }
```

that how i can rotate a circle around the path.

now the path class have this code on enterframe:

```
    private function this_enterframe(e:Event=null):void
    {
        for(var i:int = 0; i < numCircles; i++)
        {
            getCircleAt(i).aPosition += direction == RIGHT ? -speed : speed;


        }
    }
```

the images on the circles are dynamics and also the text but it was shaking before i added them.

the framerate is 30 i tried also 25 20 40 and it alwas shaking??

please give me a clue.

UPDATE:
i added in the circle class constructor:

```
      z = 1
```

like @Sean Fujiwara advised in there is a big improvement

here is a link: http://aradon.co.il/test2/circle.htm

but steel the client said to me that it steel not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it sounds like you're in a hurry, try putting this in the `Path` constructor:

```
z = 1;
```

You can see it's now doing sub-pixel rendering if you set the `speed = 0.00001`.

Also, I see you're setting `cacheAsBitmap = true` in the path object.  That is only bad for performance.

Comment: i try that also, sound Tricky (;

Comment: the z = 1 trick give big improvement!!! check: http://aradon.co.il/test2/circle.htm

Comment: That's great.  If you want to know how I figured it out (besides knowing about that trick), I dropped your swf into [SWFWire Debugger](http://www.swfwire.com/debugger) and played with the properties until it was smooth.

Answer (score 1):

`cacheAsBitmap` might help a little if you set it in the Circle class. It wont help, and actually might hurt, if you set it on the main class. You'll get the best boost from `cacheAsBitmap` when setting it on a DisplayObject whose children do no change, so it can cache it once and then only translate that object around the stage. If the children are moving (like in the case on your `parent`), then it has to redraw and recache that element every frame, and you don't get any performance boost. `cacheAsBitmap` really works best on elements that have complex vector graphics that are painful to redraw but rarely change.

I don't think that rounding your x and y values will help, I've never had much of a problem with setting fractional x,y. For vector graphics it usually does a pretty good job at subpixel placement, and for bitmaps it usually works the way I would expect it.

I think you may want to use some framerate-independent animation. The way your code is structured now, every frame render you are moving a specific number of degrees. That means that if the framerate stutters for whatever reason, then you'll still going to move the same number of pixels.

Here is the direction that I would go:

First your enter frame event handler gets a few updates. `getTimer()` returns the current number of milliseconds since the swf started. So by remembering the `lastTime` we rendered and subtracting the `currentTime` we should be able to determine exactly how many milliseconds have passed since the last frame. We can then update our circle using that time rather than an arbitrary speed/distance.

```
private var lastTime:int;

private function this_enterframe(e:Event = null):void {
    var currentTime:int = getTimer();
    var elapsedTime:int = currentTime - lastTime;
    lastTime = currentTime;

    for(var i:int = 0; i<numCircles; i++)
    {
        getCircleAt(i).updatePosition(elapsedTime, direction)
    }
}
```

Then in your Circle class, we should be able to calculate how far it should have moved during a length of time (in this case I have entered its speed as number of radians per second that it should move).

Something like:

```
public class Circle extends MovieClip {

    // Set the default speed to 10 degrees per second
    public const DEFAULT_SPEED:Number = 10 * Math.PI / 180;

    private var _radiansPerSecond = Circle.DEFAULT_SPEED;
    private var _rotationPosition:Number = 0;

    public function updatePosition(elapsedTime:int, direction:*):void { 
        var chng:Number = _radiansPerSecond * (elapsedTime / 1000) * (direction == RIGHT ? -1 : 1);
        _rotationPosition += chng;
        this.x = Math.cos(_rotationPosition) * (parentPath.width / 2);
        this.y = Math.sin(_rotationPosition) * (parentPath.height / 2); 
    }
}
```

Between using radians instead of degrees and dynamically figuring out how far a circle should move based on the time elapsed since the last render, I think you should be able to mitigate the shakiness that you are seeing.

Comment: thank you for your very useful information but it dont slove it

Answer (score 0):

try setting `cacheAsBitmap` to `true` on each moving DisplayObject. This may smooth out your animations.

If your circles are bitmaps then you can try turning smoothing on also.

Comment: i tried that everywhere in the circles or in the main class, or in the path and it was not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure your `x` and `y` positions are integers, there's no such thing as a half pixel but Flash tries to make it happen anyway.. **sigh**

It should be as simple as rounding your `x` and `y` values:

```
x = Math.round( Math.cos(aRadians) * (parentPath.width / 2) );
y = Math.round( Math.sin(aRadians) * (parentPath.height / 2) );
```

Comment: it just make them shake harder!

Answer (score 0):

I get this if I try to animate text.  So, to fix it, I just break the text apart (click the text and hit CTRL+B twice).

Are your images of those little men broken apart?  Try selecting one, and breaking it (hitting CTRL+B).  Also, that text inside the circles, if it's static text, just try breaking it to see if that fixes the shaking.

Answer (score 0):

Draw your circles into bitmaps, then apply smoothing.

Answer (score -1):

`e.updateAfterEvent();`.

But to use this you needs to use `Timer` class.

This will increase smoothness while things happen.